# Distance and Velocity estimation from FMCW radar Transceiver (KLD-7 by RFbeam)

Tags: fft, radar

Module that I am using is [KLD-7 radar Transceiver](https://rfbeam.ch/product/k-lc7-radar-transceiver/) from RFbeam

I am new to FMCW radar systems and I recently started working on distance and velocity calculations from such a system. Although the module provides the built-in functionality to calculate distance and velocity, I want to replicate those measurements using the raw ADC data that the module provides.

According to the datasheet:

> The module outputs the 256 samples of I/Q ADC data of receiver Rx1 and Rx2 for frequency A and Rx1 ADC data for frequency B.

This is the plot of those IF frequencies that I receive in the ADC data when I move an object in front of the module.
[image: IF frequencies]

Now while researching the topic I found that the distance can be calculated by taking the FFT (called the range FFT reference: [Texas Instruments](https://training.ti.com/intro-mmwave-sensing-fmcw-radars-module-1-range-estimation)):

> location of the peaks in the frequency spectrum directly corresponds to the range of objects.

I tried to measure the distance and velocity of an object 15.5cm in front using this basic understanding the results for a few trials are:

1. Distance: -14.66, Speed: -3.66
2. Distance: -40.06, Speed: -10.01
3. Distance: 8.8, Speed: 2.2
4. Distance: 0, Speed: 0

```
def calculate_velocity_distance(IF1, IF2): # Only using IF1AI and IF2AI
    # Perform FFT on the IF signals
    fft_IF1 = np.fft.fft(IF1)
    fft_IF2 = np.fft.fft(IF2)
    # Find the peaks in the FFT
    peaks_IF1, _ = find_peaks(np.abs(fft_IF1))
    peaks_IF2, _ = find_peaks(np.abs(fft_IF2))
    c = 3*10^8 # speed of light
    # Estimate the frequency of the peaks
    f1 = peaks_IF1[np.argmax(np.abs(fft_IF1[peaks_IF1]))]
    f2 = peaks_IF2[np.argmax(np.abs(fft_IF2[peaks_IF2]))]
    
    if f1==f2:
        # Object is stationary
        velocity = 0
        distance = 0
    else:
        # Object is moving
        velocity = (2 * (f2 - f1) * c) / (f1 + f2)
        distance = (c * (f2 - f1)) / (2 * (f1 + f2))
    return velocity, distance
```

I can't make sense of the above results as the code should return (0, 0) when the object is stationary.

Another problem is that in order to calculate distance I either need the time information of returned signal or the sampling rate of the ADC or the time-sweep of the chirp all of which are unknown (not provided in the datasheet).

So how can I find the distance and velocity of objects in front of the module?

Comment: you're clipping. That's bad. Reduce gain.

Comment: don't have that much control over radar parameters and the graph is clipped maybe because the object was too close to the radar as the range of the radar was set to 5m and in reality, targets will will be at least 2-3m away and the range will be set at 30m.